# How to allow user to choose when to stop each of three columns from rotating

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm writing a simple fruit machine slot in console. I have managed to create 3 separate arrays to simulate 'wheels' of the machine. Each array contains of 6 random generated characters which then 'move' upwards by swapping characters in the array. I would like to ask you for some sort of hint, how would you solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

I think the problem might be in the way I've done the 'wheels'. When I have while loop; wheels are spinning but I cannot figure out how to stop each wheel. Iv'e tried to use if statements with "GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE))" inside the while loop, but once space was released it kept spinning again and this was solving only part of my problem because I have three wheels.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib> // system cls
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>


using namespace std;

void SetCursorPosition(int x, int y);
char printRandomChar(int n);
void wheel0();
void assignWheel0Char();

int const arraySize = 6;
int coursor_x = 1;
int coursor_y = 1;

char wheelArray[arraySize];


int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));



    assignWheel0Char();



    bool playing_game = true;
    while (playing_game)
    {

        wheel0();



        Sleep(500);

    }
    std::cin.get();
}


void SetCursorPosition(int x, int y)
{
    HANDLE output = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD position = { x,y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(output, position);
}


void wheel0()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)

    {

        SetCursorPosition(coursor_x, coursor_y);
        cout << wheelArray[i];
        coursor_y++;

    }

    char temp;
    temp = wheelArray[0];
    wheelArray[0] = wheelArray[1];
    wheelArray[1] = wheelArray[2];
    wheelArray[2] = wheelArray[3];
    wheelArray[3] = wheelArray[4];
    wheelArray[4] = temp;


    coursor_y = 1;


}

void assignWheel0Char()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        wheelArray[i] = printRandomChar(1);
    }

}

char printRandomChar(int n)
{
    char alphabet[6] = { 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'W', 'L', 'D' };

    char res{};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        res = res + alphabet[rand() % 6];

    return res;
}
```

I want to allow user to stop each wheel by using space bar so it looks like this:

1.Game starts wheels are spinning, user presses space bar,  wheel1 stops , 
   but other two wheels keeps spinning. 
2. Another space bar press, now wheel1 is stoped and wheel2 stops while
   wheel 3 keeps spinning. 
3. Last space bar press stops wheel3.
4. Score is displayed if symbols match
5. User is asked if he wants to play again

Comment: Use a variable which indicates how many wheels are spinning (`int spin = 3;`). Every time space is pressed decrement the variable. Wait for space to be released again before you look for the next press (use another flag variable to keep track of when space is pressed and released).

Comment: Hi xBlu3, does the answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to allow user to stop each wheel by using space bar so it looks
>   like this:
>
> 1.Game starts wheels are spinning, user presses space bar, wheel1 stops , but other two wheels keeps spinning. 2. Another space bar
>   press, now wheel1 is stoped and wheel2 stops while wheel 3 keeps
>   spinning. 3. Last space bar press stops wheel3. 4. Score is displayed
>   if symbols match 5. User is asked if he wants to play again

The following is an example implementation you can refer to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib> // system cls
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>


using namespace std;

#define MAX_COLUMN_POSITION 3
#define SCORE_COLUMN_POSITION (MAX_COLUMN_POSITION + 1)
#define FINAL_COLUMN_POSITION (SCORE_COLUMN_POSITION + 1)

void SetCursorPosition(SHORT y, SHORT x = 1);
char printRandomChar(int n);
void wheel0();
void assignWheel0Char();

int const arraySize = 6;

char wheelArray[arraySize];

int spaceCnt = 0;
bool playing_game = true;

DWORD WINAPI GetUserInput(LPVOID lpThreadParameter)
{
    while (playing_game)
    {
        char c = _getch();

        switch (c)
        {
        case ' ':
        {
            spaceCnt++;
            if (spaceCnt >= MAX_COLUMN_POSITION)
            {
                SetCursorPosition(SCORE_COLUMN_POSITION);
                cout << "\n Score: ";               
            }
        }
        break;
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
        {
            spaceCnt = 0;
        }
        break;
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
        {
            playing_game = FALSE;
        }
        break;
        default:
            break;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}


int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    assignWheel0Char();

    CreateThread(NULL, 0, GetUserInput, NULL, 0, NULL);

    cout << "Enter SPACE key to stop one wheel. Enter Y(Yes) to play again, enter N (No) to exit. \n";

    while (playing_game)
    {

        wheel0();



        Sleep(500);

    }
    SetCursorPosition(FINAL_COLUMN_POSITION);
    cout << "\n Exiting...";
    std::cin.get();
}


void SetCursorPosition(SHORT y, SHORT x)
{
    HANDLE output = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD position = { x,y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(output, position);
}


void wheel0()
{

    for (SHORT i = 0, coursor_y = 1; i < MAX_COLUMN_POSITION; i++, coursor_y++)

    {
        if (spaceCnt > 0 && spaceCnt >= coursor_y)
            continue;
        SetCursorPosition(coursor_y);
        cout << wheelArray[i];      

    }

    char temp;
    temp = wheelArray[0];
    wheelArray[0] = wheelArray[1];
    wheelArray[1] = wheelArray[2];
    wheelArray[2] = wheelArray[3];
    wheelArray[3] = wheelArray[4];
    wheelArray[4] = temp;
}

void assignWheel0Char()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        wheelArray[i] = printRandomChar(1);
    }

}

char printRandomChar(int n)
{
    char alphabet[6] = { 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'W', 'L', 'D' };

    char res{};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        res = res + alphabet[rand() % 6];

    return res;
}
```